# Ruby on Rails default option value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I am using an array to store my values for a f.select dropdown in my form

```
   <%= f.label :country_of_origin %>
   <%= f.select :country_of_origin, [['Wales'],['Scotland'],['England']] %>
```

Rather than the default value being Wales I would like it to say "Please Select" (obviously don’t want to be able to post the value "please select). Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%= f.select("model_name", "model_id", [['Wales'],['Scotland'],['England']], {:include_blank => 'Please Select..'}) %>
```

Comment: thanks, can i ask why we are specifying the model name and model id ?

Comment: I printed the above method in my console and I got this

"<select id=\"model_name_model_id\" name=\"model_name[model_id]\"><option value=\"\">Please Select..</option>\n<option value=\"Wales\">Wales</option>\n<option value=\"Scotland\">Scotland</option>\n<option value=\"England\">England</option></select>"

the name attributes are the ones which get sent to the server in a hash. and id is to identify a unique element.